# How to bind transient oData object to detail view

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

In my SAPUI5 app I'm using odata v4 model to communicate with the server. I have a detail view that binds to an existing object something like this:

```
// Controller code:
this.getView().bindElement({
                    path: "/Objects(" + this.m_ObjectId + ")",
                    model: "modelName"
                });
```

If I want to create a new item in that view instead, I'm not binding to an existing item of course. From [the documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/c9723f8265f644af91c0ed941e114d46) I saw that one should create new items like this:

```
var oModel = this.getModel("modelName");
var oListBinding = oModel.bindList('/Objects');
var oNewKap = oListBinding.create({
    'OBJECT_ID': 0,
    'SOME_PROP': 'Test'
});
```

The question now his, how to bind that newly created (transient) object to my view? If I do a

```
this.getView().bindElement({
                        path: "/Objects(0)",
                        model: "modelName"
                    });
```

The app will try to fetch an existing item from the server again...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, anyone willing to name a reasing for downvoting?

Comment: Did you try without providing an ID so that the framework can generate a temp one? It was 'createEntry' in v2.ODataModel... Not too familiar with v4. Kind of weird that the create method only exists on ListBinding :/

Comment: Thx! After all what I've tried I'm not sure if I did test without id. I'll try next week, since I have no chance at the moment to access that code. And yes: oData v4 support is really confusing.I'll keep this updated.

Comment: How do you create a new item from a page which displays details of an existing item? From a UX aspect, I don't see how this makes sense.

Comment: I'm using routing with value ID=0 from anywhere in the application (or even as entry page if needed). The detail page then should handle the creation of the new item.

Comment: It's no problem to create a new item with oListBinding.create(). I can see that a new object is beeing transmitted on oModel.submitBatch(). My only problem is how to bind that object to my detail view without fetching it first from my server.

Comment: If you want to work with a transient entry (which for the moment only exists on client side) you can create one with sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.createEntry(). It will return a context which you can use to bind against your view.

Answer (score 0):

You may do `this.getView().setBindingContext(oNewKap)`